# Multi-Instance usage of S-Functions (C code) in SIMULINK

Tags: code-generation, simulink, s-function

I have a legacy C function in my SIMULINK model that uses some static variables in its functions. The static variables are available globally. When I reference multiple instance of my model, I get error because my S-function is not configured for that. I am getting this error message because code generation doesn't allow this.

The error message I get is the following:

> The S-Function block 'ECDCTRL/PULDESC/S-Function Builder' is not supported in multi-instance Normal mode because it does not declare that it supports multiple execution instances. If the S-Function satisfies the multiple execution instances requirements, you can declare this using the SimStruct function 'ssSupportsMultipleExecInstances' in the 'mdlSetWorkWidths' method.

I am using the `(MYSFUNC)_Outputs_Wrapper.c` file when I build it with the auto-generated code. How can I make sure that I can use my legacy C function when using multiple references of my model? SIMULINK website suggests using `ssSupportsMultipleExecInstances(SimStruct *S, bool flag)` method, but it is not correct as I am not using the `SimStruct` header files. What is the way around?

Comment: You have a general problem with static variables and multiple instances. Consider using DWork vectors in your SFunction instead.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more? I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

Use DWork vectors instead of static variables. Quoting from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/about-dwork-vectors.html):

> DWork vectors have several advantages:
>
> ```
> Provide instance-specific storage for block variables
> Eliminate static and global variables
> ```

Comment: Thanks! A colleague of mine came up with a SIMULINk based solution and replace the S-function block. phew!!