# Multiples instances of a C-Mex function and shared memory

Tags: c++, c, matlab, shared-memory, simulink

I have an C-Mex S-function that implements a Tutsin - Eulor PECE algorithm.

The function is worky perfectly fine, if only one block is present in the model. If I put several instances of the block, to filter several signals, then the outputs starts to be null.

I think that the difference instances of the function share the same memory, and this mess with my states vectors. I am not using the discrete state functions provided by MatLab, instead I use my own declared arrays of doubles (real_T ) which are not extern.

Any lead about this would be appreciated.

The code can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5nfdnio6qqrizq/te_pece.c?dl=0

Or under:

```
/*  File    : toto.c
*  Abstract:
*
*      Implements a Tutsin-Euler PECE algorithm.
*
*      This block implements a time transfer function discretisation
*      using Tutsin as a predictor and Euler as a corrector.
*
*      This block is capable of receiving multiple inputs at once (bus / vector)
*      and will treat them as separate signals to be processed by the same TF.
*
*      Use in real time, fixed step, environment.
*
*
*/

#define S_FUNCTION_NAME toto
#define S_FUNCTION_LEVEL 2

#include "simstruc.h"

#include "matrix.h"
#include "mex.h"

#define NUMERATOR_IDX 0
#define NUMERATOR_PARAM(S) ssGetSFcnParam(S,NUMERATOR_IDX)

#define DENOMINATOR_IDX 1
#define DENOMINATOR_PARAM(S) ssGetSFcnParam(S,DENOMINATOR_IDX)

#define SAMPLE_TIME_IDX 2
#define SAMPLE_TIME(S) ssGetSFcnParam(S,SAMPLE_TIME_IDX)

#define NPARAMS 3

/*====================*
* Private members    *
*====================*/
#define NSAMPLES 3
typedef enum {
    eN = 0,
    eNplusOne = 1,
    eNplusTwo = 2}
rankEnum;

typedef enum {
    eNcd = 0,
    eStatesProcessed = 1,
    eOutputProcessed = 2}
rankProcessState;
rankProcessState mProcessState;

int_T mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates;
int_T mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates;
int_T mNumberOfInputSignals;

int_T mLoopIndex;

int_T mInputWidth;

real_T* mNumerator;
real_T* mDenominator;

real_T** mPredictedStateVector;
real_T** mCorrectedStateVector;
real_T** mPredictedFunction;
real_T** mCorrectedFunction;
/*====================*
* Private methods *
*====================*/
void mInitializeRecursion();

void mComputePredictedStates(real_T iSampleTime, rankEnum iComputedRank, rankEnum iPreviousRank);
void mComputeCorrectedStates(real_T iSampleTime, rankEnum iComputedRank, rankEnum iPreviousRank);
void mComputePredictedFunction(real_T iInput, rankEnum iComputedRank);
void mComputeCorrectedFunction(real_T iInput, rankEnum iComputedRank);

void mUpdateStateVectors();

/* Function: mEmitWarning ===============================================
* Abstract:
*    Display iMessage in matlab console
*    
*/
void mEmitWarning(const char* iMessage)
{
    mxArray *cell_array_ptr;

    cell_array_ptr = mxCreateCellMatrix((mwSize)1,1);
    mxSetCell(cell_array_ptr,(mwIndex)0,mxCreateString(iMessage));
    mexCallMATLAB(0,NULL,1,&cell_array_ptr,"disp");
}

/*====================*
* S-function methods *
*====================*/

/* Function: mdlInitializeSizes ===============================================
* Abstract:
*    The sizes information is used by Simulink to determine the S-function
*    block's characteristics (number of inputs, outputs, states, etc.).
*/
static void mdlInitializeSizes(SimStruct *S)
{
    ssSetNumSFcnParams(S, NPARAMS);  /* Number of expected parameters */

    if (!ssSetNumInputPorts(S, 1)) return;
    ssSetInputPortWidth(S, 0, DYNAMICALLY_SIZED);   
    ssSetInputPortDirectFeedThrough(S,0,true);

    if (!ssSetNumOutputPorts(S, 1)) return; 
    ssSetOutputPortWidth(S, 0, DYNAMICALLY_SIZED);

    ssSetNumDiscStates(S, 1);
}

/* Function: mdlInitializeSampleTimes =========================================
* Abstract:
*    Specifiy that we inherit our sample time from the driving block.
*/
static void mdlInitializeSampleTimes(SimStruct *S)
{
    ssSetSampleTime(S, 0, *mxGetPr(SAMPLE_TIME(S)));
    ssSetOffsetTime(S, 0, 0.0);
}

#define MDL_INITIALIZE_CONDITIONS
/* Function: mdlInitializeConditions ========================================
* Abstract:
*    Initialize the discrete states to zero and
*    allocate for states and function vectors
*/
static void mdlInitializeConditions(SimStruct *S)
{   
    int_T wDenominatorLength;
    int_T wNumeratorLength;
    real_T* wNumerator;

    mInputWidth = ssGetInputPortWidth(S,0);
    ssSetOutputPortWidth(S, 0, mInputWidth);

    //Avoid repetitive use of mxGetPr/mxGetNumberOfElements by fetching datas once.
    wNumeratorLength    = mxGetNumberOfElements(NUMERATOR_PARAM(S));
    wDenominatorLength  = mxGetNumberOfElements(DENOMINATOR_PARAM(S));

    wNumerator   = mxGetPr(NUMERATOR_PARAM(S));
    mDenominator = mxGetPr(DENOMINATOR_PARAM(S));

    mNumberOfInputSignals = ssGetInputPortWidth(S,0);
    mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates = wDenominatorLength - 1;
    mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates = mNumberOfInputSignals*mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates;

    ssSetNumContStates(S, 0);
    ssSetNumDiscStates(S, mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates);        

    //Ensure identical sizes for numerator and number of states, for matrix computations
    mNumerator = calloc(wDenominatorLength,sizeof(real_T));
    if(wNumeratorLength < mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates)
    {   
        memcpy(mNumerator+(mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates-wNumeratorLength),wNumerator,wNumeratorLength*sizeof(real_T));
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(mNumerator,wNumerator,mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates*sizeof(real_T));
    }

    //Allocating for keeping in memory from n to n+2
    mPredictedStateVector = calloc(mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates, sizeof(real_T));
    mCorrectedStateVector = calloc(mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates, sizeof(real_T));
    mPredictedFunction = calloc(mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates, sizeof(real_T));
    mCorrectedFunction = calloc(mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates, sizeof(real_T));
    for (mLoopIndex = 0; mLoopIndex < mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates; mLoopIndex++)
    {
        mPredictedStateVector[mLoopIndex] = calloc(NSAMPLES, sizeof(real_T));
        mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex] = calloc(NSAMPLES, sizeof(real_T));
        mPredictedFunction[mLoopIndex] = calloc(NSAMPLES, sizeof(real_T));
        mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex] = calloc(NSAMPLES, sizeof(real_T));
    }

    mInitializeRecursion(S);
}

/* Function: mdlOutputs =======================================================
* Abstract:
*      y = Cx + Du 
*
*      The discrete system is evaluated using a controllable state space
*      representation of the transfer function.  
*
*/
static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
    int_T wStateIndex;
    real_T *wOutput = ssGetOutputPortRealSignal(S,0);   

    if (eStatesProcessed == mProcessState  && ssIsSampleHit(S, 0, tid))
    {
        for (mLoopIndex = 0; mLoopIndex < mNumberOfInputSignals; mLoopIndex++)
        {
            if(NULL != wOutput)
            {
                *wOutput = 0;
                for (wStateIndex = 0; wStateIndex < mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates; wStateIndex++)
                {
                    *wOutput  += mNumerator[wStateIndex]* mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex*mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates+wStateIndex][eNplusTwo];           
                }               
                *wOutput++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        mUpdateStateVectors();
        mProcessState = eOutputProcessed;
    }
}

#define MDL_UPDATE
/* Function: mdlUpdate ======================================================
* Abstract:
*      dx = Ax + Bu 
*      The discrete system is evaluated using a controllable state space
*      representation of the transfer function.  
*
*/

static void mdlUpdate(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
    InputRealPtrsType wInput; 
    real_T wSampleTime; 

    if ((eOutputProcessed == mProcessState || eNcd == mProcessState) && ssIsSampleHit(S, 0, tid))
    {
        wInput = (InputRealPtrsType)ssGetInputPortSignalPtrs(S,0);
        wSampleTime = *mxGetPr(SAMPLE_TIME(S));

        if(wInput != NULL)
        {
            mComputePredictedStates(wSampleTime,eNplusTwo,eNplusOne);
            mComputePredictedFunction(*wInput[0],eNplusTwo);

            mComputeCorrectedStates(wSampleTime,eNplusTwo,eNplusOne);
            mComputeCorrectedFunction(*wInput[0],eNplusTwo);

            mProcessState = eStatesProcessed;
        }
    }
}

/* Function: mdlTerminate =====================================================
* Abstract:
*    Free memory
*/
static void mdlTerminate(SimStruct *S)
{
    UNUSED_ARG(S); /* unused input argument */

    free(mNumerator) ;

    free(mPredictedStateVector) ;
    free(mCorrectedStateVector) ;
    free(mPredictedFunction) ;
    free(mCorrectedFunction) ;
}

#ifdef  MATLAB_MEX_FILE    /* Is this file being compiled as a MEX-file? */
#include "simulink.c"      /* MEX-file interface mechanism */
#else
#include "cg_sfun.h"       /* Code generation registration function */
#endif

/*====================*
* Private methods    *
*====================*/

/* Function: mInitializeRecursion =======================================================
* Abstract:
*      
*
*/
void mInitializeRecursion()
{
    mProcessState = eNcd;

    if (mCorrectedFunction !=NULL)
    {
        mCorrectedFunction[mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates-1][eNplusOne] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        mEmitWarning("Error in mdlInitializeConditions: Vectors are null");
    }
}

/* Function: mComputePredictedStates =======================================================
* Abstract:
*      
*
*/
void mComputePredictedStates(real_T iSampleTime, rankEnum iComputedRank, rankEnum iPreviousRank)
{
    if (mPredictedStateVector != NULL && mCorrectedStateVector !=NULL && mCorrectedFunction !=NULL)
    {
        for (mLoopIndex = 0; mLoopIndex < mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates; mLoopIndex++)
        {
            mPredictedStateVector[mLoopIndex][iComputedRank]  = mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex][iPreviousRank] + 1/(double)2*iSampleTime*(3*mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][iPreviousRank] - mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][eN]);                  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mEmitWarning("Error in mComputePredictedStates: Vectors are null");
    }
}

/* Function: mComputeCorrectedStates =======================================================
* Abstract:
*      
*
*/
void mComputeCorrectedStates(real_T iSampleTime, rankEnum iComputedRank, rankEnum iPreviousRank)
{
    if (mCorrectedStateVector != NULL && mCorrectedStateVector !=NULL && mPredictedFunction !=NULL)
    {
        for (mLoopIndex = 0; mLoopIndex < mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates; mLoopIndex++)
        {
            mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex][iComputedRank]  = mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex][iPreviousRank] + 1/(double)2*iSampleTime*(mPredictedFunction[mLoopIndex][iComputedRank] + mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][iPreviousRank]);         
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mEmitWarning("Error in mComputeCorrectedStates: Vectors are null");
    }
}

/* Function: mComputePredictedFunction =======================================================
* Abstract:
*      
*
*/
void mComputePredictedFunction(real_T iInput, rankEnum iComputedRank)
{
    int_T wStateIndex;
    if (mPredictedStateVector != NULL && mPredictedFunction !=NULL)
    {
        for (mLoopIndex = 0; mLoopIndex < mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates; mLoopIndex++)
        {
            if(0 == (mLoopIndex+1)%mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates)
            {
                mPredictedFunction[mLoopIndex][iComputedRank] = iInput;
                for (wStateIndex = 0; wStateIndex < mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates; wStateIndex++)
                {
                    mPredictedFunction[mLoopIndex][iComputedRank]  += -1*mDenominator[mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates-wStateIndex]* mPredictedStateVector[wStateIndex][iComputedRank];            
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mPredictedFunction[mLoopIndex][iComputedRank]  = mPredictedStateVector[mLoopIndex+1][iComputedRank];    
            }       
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mEmitWarning("Error in mComputePredictedFunction: Vectors are null");
    }
}

/* Function: mComputeCorrectedFunction =======================================================
* Abstract:
*      
*
*/
void mComputeCorrectedFunction(real_T iInput, rankEnum iComputedRank)
{
    int_T wStateIndex;
    if (mCorrectedStateVector != NULL && mCorrectedFunction !=NULL)
    {
        for (mLoopIndex = 0; mLoopIndex < mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates; mLoopIndex++)
        {
            if(0 == (mLoopIndex+1)%mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates)
            {
                mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][iComputedRank] = iInput;
                for (wStateIndex = 0; wStateIndex < mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates; wStateIndex++)
                {
                    mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][iComputedRank]  += -1*mDenominator[mSignalNumberOfDiscreteStates-wStateIndex]* mCorrectedStateVector[wStateIndex][iComputedRank];            
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][iComputedRank]  = mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex+1][iComputedRank];    
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mEmitWarning("Error in mComputeCorrectedFunction: Vectors are null");
    }
}

/* Function: mUpdateStateVectors =======================================================
* Abstract:
*      
*
*/
void mUpdateStateVectors()
{
    if (mPredictedStateVector != NULL && mCorrectedStateVector !=NULL && mPredictedFunction != NULL && mCorrectedFunction !=NULL)
    {
        for (mLoopIndex = 0; mLoopIndex < mTotalNumberOfDiscreteStates; mLoopIndex++)
        {
            mPredictedStateVector[mLoopIndex][eN]  = mPredictedStateVector[mLoopIndex][eNplusOne];
            mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex][eN]  = mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex][eNplusOne];
            mPredictedFunction[mLoopIndex][eN]  = mPredictedFunction[mLoopIndex][eNplusOne];
            mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][eN]  = mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][eNplusOne];

            mPredictedStateVector[mLoopIndex][eNplusOne]  = mPredictedStateVector[mLoopIndex][eNplusTwo];
            mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex][eNplusOne]  = mCorrectedStateVector[mLoopIndex][eNplusTwo];
            mPredictedFunction[mLoopIndex][eNplusOne]  = mPredictedFunction[mLoopIndex][eNplusTwo];
            mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][eNplusOne]  = mCorrectedFunction[mLoopIndex][eNplusTwo];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mEmitWarning("Error in mUpdateStateVectors: Vectors are null");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code instead of linking to it.

Comment: All variables defined outside of an S-Function method (i.e. all the variables you have defined at the top of the file) are global in scope (i.e. there is only one instance of the variable, and all instances of the S-Function access that variable).  You need to use Work Vectors to define data scoped to each individual S-Function instance.  There are many, many examples of using Work Vectors in the documentation.

Comment: I added the code (the whole file, as the issue can be anywhere).

Comment: Phil Goddard: 
I do think you pointed to the correct problem. I will now read the doc about it, but do you have any advice on how I should use work vectors ?

Comment: Remember to allocate and **deallocate** all the memory eh! are you sure you are not leaving some there?

Comment: Ander Biguri: I freed only the one I allocated using "calloc". Should I free something else ?

Comment: @Zangdar Free everything that is a pointer and is being used. I haven't checked your code, but often library functions do allocate memory for you.

Comment: As mentioned in this very similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469428/multi-instance-usage-of-s-functions-c-code-in-simulink/20471547#20471547) and by @Phil, you should use DWork vectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I solved the issue using DWork vectors :)